# Forwarding a method with parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a problem where I am trying to have a called method forward it's own parameters to a similar method. I have an instance of a class that can be in any number of different states (it's for a game character, so: idle, walk, run, etc). In this class there are certain public methods that can always be invoked, but depending on the state of the character different actions are taken. An example of this would be:

```
public void TakeDamage(float damage)
{
    // Check what state we are in, and call a function with a similiar name

    if (state == idle)
    {
        TakeDamage_Idle(damage);
    } 
    else if (state == walk)
    {
        TakeDamage_Walk(damage);
    }
    ...and so on
}

private void TakeDamage_Idle(float damage)
{
    // Do something
}

private void TakeDamage_Walk(float damage)
{
    // Do something different
}
```

(The above is partially pseudocode). What I am trying to do is to automate the process above. I would need to be able to retrieve the name of the method I want to call (which is dependent on the state), and then call it while also passing in any parameters. The first part (getting the method name) is easy enough and can be done using Reflection. What I'm having trouble with is finding a way to pass the parameters of the called method (TakeDamage in this case) directly to the state method (TakeDamage_Idle, etc). Obviously it can be done manually like above, but I want this process to be generic so that I can apply it to any method I want.

I've tried looking into Delegates and Actions, but I can't find anything about passing a set of parameters to them. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: To clarify, my main goal is to make this process generic and repeatable. So ideally I would have a method like

```
CallStateMethod(string methodName, ??)
```

That I would be able to pass a method name into, and it would call the proper corresponding method depending on what the current state is, along with forwarding any of the original parameters to the proper state method. Of course since I'm not sure how to do this, the above method's parameters would depend on what is possible in C#. Sorry if this was originally unclear.

Comment: In this specific case, you're looking for a `Dictionary<State, Action<float>>`. Sometimes you don't need something fancy, just a simple data structure.

Comment: Reflection is bad juju. Make an interface ITakeDamage. Create classes that implement the interface.  Create a list of them in your character class. Find the right one when necessary and call it.

Comment: @Mephy: Is there any way to declare an Action with a variable set of parameters? For example, if I had multiple methods I wanted to forward that had different parameter sets, would it be possible to retrieve the parameter set from a method and pass it into the Action constructor to create it's parameter set at runtime? So that if I did it through TakeDamage(float damage) it would build Action<float>, but through SomethingElse(float p1, string p2) it would build Action<float, string>.

Comment: @dbugger: Any reason other than performance? My understanding is that caching the method (like in a Dictionary as Mephy did) would solve that, but I'm not too well versed in the pros and cons of reflection.

Comment: I don't quite agree that reflection is "bad juju"—it has its place—but would note that caching would reduce the worse performance hit (looking up the method) but not that caused by coercing into an array of objects and then back again.
But while I wouldn't go as far as "bad juju", it's not the best way to solve things most of the time, and this is almost certainly one of those times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first part (getting the method name) is easy enough and can be done using Reflection. What I'm having trouble with is finding a way to pass the parameters of the called method (TakeDamage in this case) directly to the state method (TakeDamage_Idle, etc).

Okay, you have the name, so you get the `MethodInfo`:

```
var meth = GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Once you have that, you can just `Invoke` it:

```
meth.Invoke(this, new object[]{damage});
```

But there's more than a few issues with this.

If you really have so many possible methods that it's hard to keep track of them all in the `if`-`else` branching, then create a dictionary (I'm assuming `state` is integers with constants, but the following works with `enum` and other types too):

```
Dictionary<int, Action<float>> actions = new Dictionary<int, Action<float>>();
actions[idle] = TakeDamage_Idle;
actions[walk] = TakeDamage_Walk;
…

public void TakeDamage(float damage)
{
  actions[state](damage);
}
```

Really though, while this pattern is useful sometimes, it's unlikely to be the best approach.

If the various "states" make so much difference here, do they not also make difference elsewhere? If so, you're likely to be much better off making that a type itself:

```
public interface IState
{
  void TakeDamage(float damage);
  void RegainHealth(float healing);
  /* … */
}

public class WalkingState : IState
{
  /* implement here */
}
```

Then you can move between states (this also gives much flexibility in being able to parameterise states and use parameters about walking that have no meaning when idle, and so on).

On the other hand, keeping to the `if…else` chain at least allows for greater inlining. If this is the only place where different states affect different things, you're likely better off staying with it, or even just rolling the methods into one anyway, though one can't really say for sure without knowing more about the logic involved.

Comment: Thanks very much, passing the parameters as an object[] array solves my issue. I do currently use the states in different places. Each state has a corresponding Enter_StateName, Exit_StateName, Update_StateName method. Looking at some of the responses here though, it seems there might be better ways of implementing this.

Comment: I'm now even more sure either that an interface of abstract class representing "types of state" with implementations for each state, or else a class for "state" with instance data representing details is the way to go (the latter if behaviour is mostly the same bar one or two values differing, the former otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Standard OOP solution would be to create class that handles action for "state" and just call corresponding method for current state:

```
 interface IState
 {
      void TakeDamage(float);
      ....
 }

 class WalkingState : IState
 {
      ActiveObject parent;
      public WalkingState(ActiveObject parent) { this.parent = parent;}
      public void TakeDamage(float) 
      {
          // do whatever needed including calling parent.XXX methods  
          ....
      }
      ...
 }

 class ActiveObject
 { 
     IState currentState;

     public void SetWalk () { currentState = new WalkState(this);}

     public TakeDamage(float damage)
     {
        currentState.TakeDamage(damage);
     }
     ...
 }
```

This would work nicely if there are more action that should be more-or-less uniformly handled for multiple types of objects (like "walk state" for Soldiers, Penguins, Birds).

Alternatively if you have just one or two methods that need forwarding you can have single delegate:

```
 Action<float> takeDamage;

 public void SetWalk () { takeDamage = TakeWalkingDamage;}

 public void TakeDamage(float damage)
 {
    takeDamage(damage);
 }
```

Comment: Note to self: this post does not address "methods I wanted to forward that had different parameter sets"... Probably not an answer... Will delete if clarifications from OP point to different direction.

Comment: Reading through your post it was very informative even if it didn't directly address that issue, so I wouldn't delete, since someone else might need it!

Comment: Side note, `Func<float>` is `float (void)`, and not `void (float)`.. You mean `Action<float>` instead.